# cfs:s3 how to get url after upload?

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3

I cannot understand how does cfs:s3 work.
On a client i have

```
images = new FS.Store.S3('images')

@Images = new FS.Collection "allImages",
  stores: [images]
  filter:
    allow:
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
```

On a server the same with keys.
And change event

```
"change .file-image": (e) ->
    console.log("changed!")
    FS.Utility.eachFile e, (file) ->
      Images.insert file, (err,fileObj) ->
        console.log 'fileObj',fileObj
```

And after all it a cannot understand what to do, how to upload and get url?

Comment: In JavaScript I set an interval which checks every second (of course you can set the period by your own) fileObj.isUploaded() to be true. If that's the case you get the url with fileObj.url(). Maybe this helps: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#ui-helpers

Comment: If you're on Meteor 1.3 I would recommend using Amazon's SDK directly instead of CollectionFS.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the cfs object you'll typically want to retain its `_id`, for example:

```
let imageId = Images.insert file
```

or

```
Images.insert file, (err,fileObj) ->
    let imageId = fileObj._id
```

cfs might take awhile to finish loading the file however and the url isn't available until the upload is finished.

```
let url = fileObj.isUploaded() ? fileObj.url() : null
```

In blaze that might look like:

```
{{#if this.isUploaded}}
  <a href="{{this.url}}">download the file</a>
{{else}}
  {{> progress}}
{{/if}}
```

Finally, as the cfs project is getting less attention you may wish to switch to [edgee:slingshot](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot)